# HyperLedger Fabric installation in Windows10 pro

Tags: windows, docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I'm trying to install Hyperledger Fabric in Windows10, my question is does All instructions in the hyperledger documentation are issued in the **WSL Ubuntu terminal** or **Git bash** in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows instructions were all written for Git Bash.  I believe people have also used WSL successfully, but there's no documentation specifically for WSL.